# Arduino UNO inconsistent I2C register reading from ArduCam

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, spi

I have an [Arducam](https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arduino/tree/master/ArduCAM) hooked up to an Arduino UNO.  The code I am running looks like this:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ArduCAM.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "memorysaver.h"

const int CS = 10;

ArduCAM myCAM(OV5642, CS);

void setup() {
  uint8_t vid, pid;

  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);

  SPI.begin();

  //Check if the camera module type is OV5642
  myCAM.rdSensorReg16_8(OV5642_CHIPID_HIGH, &vid);
  myCAM.rdSensorReg16_8(OV5642_CHIPID_LOW, &pid);

  if ((vid != 0x56) || (pid != 0x42))
    Serial.println("Can't find OV5642 module!");
  else
    Serial.println("OV5642 detected.");

...
```

and the rdSensorReg16_8 function from the library:

```
//I2C Write 8bit address, 16bit data
byte ArduCAM::wrSensorReg8_16(int regID, int regDat)
{
    Wire.beginTransmission(sensor_addr >> 1);
    Wire.write(regID & 0x00FF);     

    Wire.write(regDat >> 8);            // sends data byte, MSB first
    Wire.write(regDat & 0x00FF);    

    if(Wire.endTransmission())
    {
        return 0; 
    }

    delay(1);
    return(1);
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that sometimes I will receive the "Can't find OV5642 module!" message, and other times everything is fine and I receive "OV5642 detected" (I have the OV5642 module hooked up, so it should always be returning detected).

I have tried using different cables to connect the camera to my UNO.  I have tried swapping out my USB cable.  I have tried using a 12v wall adapter to power the UNO. None of these options permanently solved my problem - I still receive both messages interchangeably.

One thing that *seems* like it is adding consistency is when I change which USB port on my computer the cable is plugged into.  Every time I switch the USB port I am using, it seems like for the first run I'll receive the successful "OV5642 detected" message, but after reseting the Arduino or re-uploading my sketch, I go back to the "Can't find OV5642 module!" message.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot why I am getting inconsistent readings?  Thank you.

Comment: Same problem here. It seems like if you reset the camera (plug it out and in again) it works again. I don't know why, I also tried it with a Raspberry Pi, and I didn't have this problem (however I had other problems!).

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding a short delay before SPI.begin() and verifying that the power drawn does not exceed 500 mA.

The product description describes the power on sequence. [OV5642](http://www.uctronics.com/download/cam_module/OV5642DS.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mikael.  I added a delay and verified the power, but I am still experiencing the same issues.

Comment: Ok. Let us assume a hardware issue. Pull-up resistors on I2C wires? Might be integrated on the board. How are you connecting the device? Did you measure the power drawn? How much was it? Did the voltage drop?

Comment: Have you tried decoupling the power pins on the module? Just attach a 100uF or larger capacitor to the GND and power pins on the module.